# Does 7zip for Linux support AES-NI?

Tags: 7-zip, aes, aes-ni

I am looking to encrypt a set of fairly large files using well supported, ideally cross-platform software. I understand that 7zip uses 256 bit AES encryption.

Does anyone know if standard Linux builds of 7z can make use of AES-NI (ie CPU acceleration for AES)?

Answer (score -1):

Old article, 2010: https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/clarkdale-aes-ni-encryption,2538-9.html
That's why we also tried 7-Zip 9.1, BitLocker (in Windows 7 Ultimate), and WinZip 14, all of which are listed by Intel as AES-NI-enabled and completely valid measures of the technology's applicability in software we all use on a fairly regular basis already.

Also mentioned there that it has not much performance benefit when also compressing.

Comment: Unfortunately it appears the above answer is almost unrelated to the question, which is if there is **LINUX** support for AES-NI on 7Zip.

Comment: @davidgo I don't think Linux support is different, but I do see now that you are not referring to the `7-zip` program, but to `7z` which is indeed not tested there.